# prove if n - natural number divide number $34x^2-42xy+13y^2$ then n is sum of two square number

Tags: prime-numbers, modules, divisibility, sums-of-squares

prove if n - natural number divide number $34x^2-42xy+13y^2$ where x,y are relatively prime  then n is sum of two square number.

I don't know what is going on in this exercise. I will be grateful for explanation.

Comment: A start: The natural number $n$ divides $34(34x^2-42y+13y^2)$, which is equal to 
$(34x-21y)^2+y^2$.
Now use what you know about the prime factorization of numbers that are the sum of two squares.

Comment: But why n divides $34(34x^2 -42y+13y^2)$ ? I have that n divides $34x^2−42xy+13y^2$

Comment: If $n$ divides $A$, then $n$ divides $34A$, indeed $n$ divides $kA$.

Comment: @André Nicolas I dont think it's equal to $ (34x−21y)^2+y^2$

Comment: Maybe not, I am not that good at arithmetic. But it looks fine to me, expanding we get $34^2x^2-2(34)(21)xy+442y^2$ and $442=(13)(34)$.

Comment: I see now You're right

Comment: @André Nicolas so for example a=34x-21y, b=y so we have that gcd(a,b)=1 and n|a^2+b^2  then exist numbers k,m that n = k^2 + m^2. It's enough?

Comment: Not enough. First it is not necessarily the case that $\gcd(a,b)=1$, though it is close enough, the only possible common divisors are divisors of $34$. But temporarily let us assume they are relatively prime. Then by standard theory the only possible prime divisors of $a^2+b^2$ are $2$ and primes of the shape $4k+1$. So $n$ is a product that has no primes of the shape $4k+3$, and it follows by standard theory that $n$ is a sum of $2$ squares, since it is a product of terms that are the sum of two squares.Next time please show what you have tried. You are more likely to get a full answer.

Comment: Ok next time I will show, thank you

Comment: You are welcome. It is a nice problem, first completing the square, and then standard facts about divisors of $a^2+b^2$ when $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime. But there is a little twist, since $a$ and $b$ are not necessarily quite relatively prime.

Comment: if they wont relatively prime it will be a big problem

Comment: Not really in this case. For suppose that $d$ divides $y$ and $34x-21y$. Then $d$ divides $34x$, so since $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime, $d$ divides $34$. We have $a=dA$, $b=dB$ where $A$ and $B$ are relatively prime. Thus $a^2+b^2=d^2(A^2+B^2)$. So all prime divisors of $a^2+b^2$ are either $2$ or $17$, or prime divisors of $A^2+B^2$. We know that prime divisors of $A^2+B^2$ are $2$ or of the shape $4k+1$, and therefore the same applies to $a^2+b^2$, since $17$  is of the shape $4k+1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas the given form is positive and of discriminant $-4.$ That means there is an invertible (determinant $1$) change of variables in $SL_2 \mathbb Z,$ call it $\alpha \delta - \beta \gamma,$ that takes one form to the other, and preserves gcd. In one of the directions, it reads $(5x -3y)^2 + (-3x + 2y )^2 = 34x^2 - 42xy+ 13 y^2.$ Backwards, if $u = 2x+3y,$ $v=3x+5y,$ then $34u^2 - 42 uv + 13 v^2 = x^2 + y^2$

Comment: @WillJagy: The representation $(5x-3y)^2+(-3x+2y)^2$ is certainly nicer than the completing the square method I used, and because of relative primality saves some minor hassle at the end. Since comments are in principle evanescent, it would be useful if you wrote an answer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas glad you enjoyed it. Left an answer.

Answer (score 2):

A start: The natural number $n$ divides $34(34x^2-42y+13y^2)$, which is equal to 
$$(34x-21y)^2+y^2.$$
Now use what you know about the prime factorization of numbers that are the sum of two squares.

*Added*: We show that if $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime, then any prime divisor of $(34x-21y)^2+y^2$ is either $2$ or of the form $4k+1$.

Since $2$ is a sum of two squares, and any prime of the form $4k+1$ is a sum of two squares, we get that $n$ is a product of sums of two squares. Thus by the Brahmagupta-Fibonacci-Diophantus identity, $n$ is a sum of two squares.

So let us look at the prime divisors of $(34x-21y)^2+y^2$. Let $d$ be the gcd of $34x-21y$ and $y$. Then $d$ divides $34x$, and therefore since $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime, it follows that $d$ divides $34$.

Thus $34x-21y=dA$ and $y=dB$, where $A$ and $B$ are relatively prime. It follows that any prime divisor of $(34x-21y)^2+y^2$ is $2$ or $17$, or a prime divisor $p$ of $A^2+B^2$. Since $A$ and $B$ are relatively prime, it follows by standard theory that $p=2$ or $p$ is of the form $4k+1$. This completes the proof.

Comment: added  part of the Gauss step by step procedure ( not the specific matrices). Nothing mysterious about it, and intended for  hand calculations.

Comment: @WillJagy: Nicely explained, and permanently useful to readers. Sadly I can only upvote once.

Comment: @AndréNicolas. Nothing wrong with your answer but is easier to start with $34 x^2-42 x y+13 y^2=(5 x-3 y)^2+(3 x-2 y)^2$. And we may have $n=4^m$ which is a sum of two squares of integers, although one of the squares is zero.

Comment: @user254665: Yes, Will Jagy's representation is easier to work with, since the numbers $5x-3y$ and $3x-2y$ are relatively prime if $\gcd(x,y)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

They are asking about Gauss reduction. The given form is positive and of discriminant $−4.$ That means there is an invertible (determinant 1) change of variables in $SL_2 \mathbb Z,$ call it
$$
P =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 \alpha & \beta \\
\gamma & \delta
\end{array}
\right)
$$
 that takes one form to the other, and preserves gcd. If $u=2x+3y, v=3x+5y,$ then $$34u^2−42uv+13v^2=x^2+y^2$$
 Backwards, $$(5x−3y)^2+(−3x+2y)^2=34x^2−42xy+13y^2.$$
Here we are looking at
$$
H =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 34 & -21 \\
-21 & 13
\end{array}
\right)
$$ and
$$
P =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 2 & 3 \\
3 & 5
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Taking 
$$
Q = P^{-1} =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 5 & -3 \\
-3 & 2
\end{array}
\right),
$$

The first displayed line equation $u=2x+3y, v=3x+5y,$ $34u^2−42uv+13v^2=x^2+y^2$ is
$$ P^T H P = I, $$ the second is
$$ Q^T  Q = H. $$ The second ought to make you think of Cholesky, only with integers required.

It happens that $P$ and so $Q$ are symmetric so the transpose signs are redundant, not important.

EDIT: Gauss reduction is a step by step procedure intimately linked with the Euclidean algorithm. At each step, we are changing the symmetric matrix in the middle by multiplying on the right by either some
$$
P_j =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 1 & \beta \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
or
$$
P_j =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and keeping the running product $P_1 P_2 \cdots P_r = P.$ The changes on the triple of coefficients go this way:
$$  \langle 34, -42, 13 \rangle, $$
$$  \langle 13, 42, 34 \rangle, $$
$$  \langle 13, -10, 2 \rangle, $$
$$  \langle 2, 10, 13 \rangle, $$
$$  \langle 2, 2, 1 \rangle, $$
$$  \langle 1, -2, 2 \rangle, $$
$$  \langle 1, 0, 1 \rangle. $$
The particular string $P_1 P_2 \cdots P_6 = P$ that accomplishes this is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 1 & -2 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 1 & -2 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 2 & 3 \\
3 & 5
\end{array}
\right)
$$