# Equation involving the Jacobi symbol: $\left( \frac {-6} p \right) = 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity, jacobi-symbol

I have to determine the values of $p \in \{0, \dots, 23 \}$ such that $\left( \frac {-6} p \right) = 1$.

I have that:
$$\left( \frac {-6} p \right) = \left( \frac 2 p \right) \left( \frac {-3} p \right)$$

and I know that $\left( \frac 2 p \right) = 1$ if $p \equiv 1,7 \pmod 8$ and $\left( \frac 2 p \right) = -1$ if $p \equiv 3,5 \pmod 8$, and also that $\left( \frac {-3} p \right) = 1$ if $p\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, I find that $p\equiv 1,?,7,?\pmod{24}$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $10$ is not coprime to $24$ and $\frac{-6}{10}$ is not an integer, so how could $10$ possible be a solution?

Comment: The $6$ and $10$ should be $5$ and $11$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak by chinese remainder you have $2.3$ and $2.5$

Comment: @AlexM. I edited this question because I thought it was hard to read and because it wasn't using $\pmod{24}$ notation, but if you click the "edited [time] ago" link, you can see the original version. I have no idea what the Jacobi symbol is, so my edits may have messed up Maman's notation. I'm really sorry for any ambiguity I caused!

Comment: @NobleMushtak: Indeed, you have omitted a pair of parantheses and so have completely changed the meaning of the question. Let me fix it.

Comment: @NobleMushtak: Those things that had parantheses around them (that you have deleted) are not fractions, they are [Jacobi symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol).

Comment: @AndréNicolas by chinese remainder you have 2x3 and 2x5 ?

Comment: @AlexM. I know basic modular arithmetic and the totient function, but have never heard of this before, so thank you so much for teaching me about this!

Comment: To use the correct terminology, it should be find the primes $p$ such that $\left(\frac{-6}{p}\right)=1$. Express the answer modulo $24$.

Comment: @Maman: Is $p$ supposed to be prime?

Comment: You took care of $p\equiv 1, 7$ modulo $8$, $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$. Now you have to deal with $p\equiv 3,5$ modulo $8$, $p\equiv 2\pmod{3}$. The first gives $p\equiv 11\pmod{24}$. The second gives $p\equiv 5\pmod{24}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $(-6/p)=1$ if (i) $(2/p)=1$ and $(3/p)=1$ or (ii) $(2/p)=-1$ and $(3/p)=-1$.

You seem to have taken care of (i). We get the solutions $p\equiv 1\pmod{24}$ and $p\equiv 7\pmod{24}$.

For (ii) we want a) $p\equiv 3\pmod{8}$ and $p\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ or b) $p\equiv 5\pmod{8}$ and $p\equiv 2\pmod{3}$.

a) has the solution $p\equiv 11\pmod{24}$ and b) has the solution $p\equiv 5\pmod{24}$.

Comment: the second case is also the chinese remaider theorem ?

Comment: Yes, in principle for example we use the CRT to find the solution of the system $x\equiv 3\pmod{8}$, $x\equiv 2\pmod{3}$. However, the numbers are very small, so we go through the numbers less than $24$ which are congruent to $3$ mod $8$. These are $3,11,19$. Now we pick the one aong these which is congruent to $2$ modulo $3$. This is $11$.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this the other day as well. Call this a side note, the primes $1,7 \pmod {24}$ are all represented by $x^2 + 6 y^2.$ It is easy to see that if $p = x^2 + 6 y^2$ in integers, then $(-6|p) = 1.$ 
$$   1,      7,     31,     73,     79,     97,    103,    127,    151,    193,
    199,
 $$

the primes $5,11 \pmod {24}$ are all represented by $2x^2 + 3 y^2.$ 
$$       2,      3,      5,     11,     29,     53,     59,     83,    101,    107,
    131,    149,    173,    179,    197,
$$
Of course, $2x^2 + 3 y^2$ also represents $2$ and $3,$ but those divide $6.$

Meanwhile, IF $(-6|p)= 1,$ it is easy enough to construct a (positive) binary quadratic form $f(x,y) = p x^2 + Bxy + C y^2$ of discriminant $-24,$ and this form reduces to one of the two indicated forms above; that process tells us how to represent $p.$ For part of that, [prove if n - natural number divide number $34x^2-42xy+13y^2$ then n is sum of two square number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816083/prove-if-n-natural-number-divide-number-34x2-42xy13y2-then-n-is-sum-of-tw/1816307#1816307)

Why not: if $(-6|p)= 1,$ then $(-24|p)= 1,$ we have some integer solution to $\beta^2 \equiv -24 \pmod p.$ If the original $\beta$ we found was odd, replace it by $B= p - \beta$ so that $B$ is even, and $B^2 \equiv -24 \pmod {4p}.$ That is, $B^2 = -24 + 4pC.$ Well, $B^2 - 4pC = -24,$ and the positive binary quadratic form $\langle p, B, C \rangle$ has discriminant $-24.$ The notation $\langle p, B, C \rangle$ means the form $f(x,y) = p x^2 + Bxy + C y^2$